# rosjava (android_core) pub sub example nodes isolated

Tags: java, android, ros

I'm trying to connect the android pubsub tutorial of android_core with a master core in my server.

Actually the example runs fine and I'm able to see the android subscriber getting the messages in the listener activity, which are sent from the talker node written in rosjava.

And when I run an additional listener node, it seems to subscribe fine:

```
rostopic info /chatter
Type: std_msgs/String

Publishers: 
 * /rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/talker (http://10.0.2.15:45508/)

Subscribers: 
 * /listener_6323_1412952506377 (http://laptop:37300/)
 * /android_gingerbread/ros_text_view (http://10.0.2.15:47832/)
```

The graph should look like this:

|/listener_6323_1412952506377 |-------> | /rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/talker |
|/android_gingerbread/ros_text_view |-> |---------------------------------|

So, the problem is that even if it is subscribed, it won't see anything, the messages sent by the talker in the emulator arrive fine to the listener in the emulator, but not to the outside listener. Also I tried to send messages from the console, and they are received fine by the listener in the console, but the listener in the emulator won't see it. Also, I noticed that when I run rqt_graph, it stops working right after I launch the android APP.

I'm using the ROS_MASTER_URI set to my IP, in both console and emulator, so there shouldn't be mismatches in the namespace.

What could be happening here?, Namespace problem of the messages?, version incompatibility problem?.
IDK.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the Android emulator, that isolates the network interface of the virtual device.
There are 2 solutions:
1) Do a port forwarding to make the nodes visible outside.
2) Get rid of the emu and use a real device.